# Trying to print name

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a code that asks the user's name and then prints the name he enters later, but when I print it the variable is null.  How do I fix this without changing the method that asks the user's name until they like it? (I marked the place I want the name to be printed with the "????")

```
public class Main {
  
  static class NamingClass {
    
    String PlayerName;

    static void ChooseName() {
      System.out.println("Enter your name:");
      Scanner ScanPlayerName = new Scanner(System.in);//Object in scanner for name
      NamingClass ObjForName = new NamingClass();//Object to use "PlayerName" String
      ObjForName.PlayerName = ScanPlayerName.nextLine(); //ask user to enter name
      System.out.println("Your  name is " + ObjForName.PlayerName + ", is this correct?");
      System.out.println("True=Yes");
      System.out.println("False=No");
      Scanner ObjToCheck = new Scanner(System.in); //Object in scanner for name check
      Boolean CheckName = ObjToCheck.nextBoolean(); //boolean is asked to user
      if(CheckName == false) {
        ChooseName(); //repeat 
      }
      else{
      }
    }
  }

  static void Credits() { //method that should print name entered in ChooseName()
    System.out.println("The player name is" /* + ?????????????*/);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NamingClass.ChooseName();
    Credits();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: When does `ObjForName` go out of scope?

Comment: Note that in Java names except class names should start with lowercase letters (`chooseName`, not `ChooseName`). Naming your items according to standard practice will help other people trying to read your code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should pass the name variable when you call the function.

```
static void Credits(string name) 
{
    System.out.println("The player name is" + name);
}
```

To get the name, NamingClass.ChooseName() will return the name

```
String name = NamingClass.ChooseName();
```

And then call:

```
Credits(name);
```

The code will be like this:

```
public class Main {

    static class NamingClass {

        static String ChooseName() {

            String PlayerName = "";
            Boolean CheckName = false;

            while (!CheckName) {
                System.out.println("Enter your name:");
                Scanner ScanPlayerName = new Scanner(System.in);//Object in scanner for name
                PlayerName = ScanPlayerName.nextLine(); //ask user to enter name
                System.out.println("Your  name is " + PlayerName + ", is this correct?");
                System.out.println("True=Yes");
                System.out.println("False=No");
                Scanner ObjToCheck = new Scanner(System.in); //Object in scanner for name check
                CheckName = ObjToCheck.nextBoolean(); //boolean is asked to user
            }

            return PlayerName;
        }
    }

    static void Credits(String name) {
        System.out.println("The player name is" + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = NamingClass.ChooseName();
        Credits(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to run your code and it doesnt work because you have to call PlayerName using and object, and even with that I get "The player name isnull"

Comment: I'm sorry. That code was wrong. I think this will work.

Comment: PlayerName is getting the error "PlayerName cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: I've just tested this code and it works fine. Let me know if you have any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is creating an object in `chooseName` .
The object is destroyed after method call and lost...
This is what you need..

```java
public class Main {
  
  static class NamingClass {
    
/*make it static and accessible..or consider getters if its private*/    
public static String PlayerName;

    static void ChooseName() {
      System.out.println("Enter your name:");
      Scanner ScanPlayerName = new Scanner(System.in); //Object in scanner for name
/* change this...      
NamingClass ObjForName = new NamingClass();//Object to use "PlayerName" String
      ObjForName.PlayerName = ScanPlayerName.nextLine(); //ask user to enter name
*/
      PlayerName = ScanPlayerName.nextLine(); //now no object is created because its static
     // System.out.println("Your  name is " + ObjForName.PlayerName + ", is this correct?");
System.out.println("Your  name is " + PlayerName + ", is this correct?");
      System.out.println("True=Yes");
      System.out.println("False=No");
      Scanner ObjToCheck = new Scanner(System.in); //Object in scanner for name check
      Boolean CheckName = ObjToCheck.nextBoolean(); //boolean is asked to user
      if(CheckName == false) {
      }
      else{
      }
    }
  }

  static void Credits() { //method that should print name entered in ChooseName()
    //System.out.println("The player name is" /* + ?????????????*/);
System.out.println("The player name is" +PlayerName);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NamingClass.ChooseName();
    Credits();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but instead of PlayerName in: 
System.out.println("The player name is" + PlayerName); 
You have to use NamingClass.PlayerName.

Comment: Sorry..i'm not used to that kind of placement of brackets..i lost track..